# How to create an aggregate function to return the last n records?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm using Postgres and would like to create an aggregate function to return the last n most recent records (according to another column).  Is this possible?  If so, how can I do this?  Or would it be better to not do this?

Looking for something like `select sum(col1) as a, last_n(col2, 5, created_date) as b from ...`'

`b` would then be an array of 5 elements.

Comment: Please add your version of Postgres.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for a window function or subquery. A PL/PgSQL aggregate function for this job wouldn't be too hard, but it'd be very inefficient because it'd be creating and destroying a lot of arrays, since arrays are immutable at the SQL level. To make it efficient you'd need to write the function in C, where you can mutate the aggregate's temp state array, at which point you get to discover the "joy" of the PostgreSQL C array API.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use use an *uncorrelated* subquery:

```
SELECT sum(col1) as a
      ,ARRAY(
          SELECT col2
          FROM   tbl t2
          ORDER  BY t2.created_date DESC
          LIMIT  5) AS b
FROM   tbl t1;
```